# Python for Beginners (function in functions)

Tags: python-3.x, function

```
pirogis_stuffings = ["potatos", "cheese", "mushrooms"]


def format_pirogis(stuffings):
    if stuffings == "potatos":
        return f"{stuffings.title()} ($10.00)"
    else:
        return f"{stuffings.title()} ($12.50)"


def print_menu(stuffings):
    print("Welcome to Marko's home made pirogis")
    print("Our available stuffings are:")
    for stuffings in stuffings:
        print(format_pirogis(stuffings))


print_menu(pirogis_stuffings)
```

my question is why do I have to have the last two lines at the end of the second function and how does it all work together? (I am self-learning and like to know how everything works, thank you)

Comment: What do you mean by "how does it all work together"?  Are you able to ask a more specific question?

Comment: The Watsonian answer is that the `print_menu` function calls the `format_pirogis` function in order to format the string appropriately, and the functions are designed this way with the logic split across the two functions because it keeps each individual function simpler. The Doylian answer is that the `print_menu` function calls the `format_pirogis` function because the pedagogical purpose of the example is to demonstrate how one function can call another.

Comment: The last two lines loop through the list "pirogis stuffings" and prints for each value the outcome of your first function format_pirogis. In format_pirogis, the function evaluates if the value is "potatos", then it gives a 10. Anything else it gives 12.50.

Comment: thanks for the helpful explanations

Comment: so, in other words, the "for loop" is calling the list?

Comment: What the `for` loop does is - for each element in the list `pirogis_stuffings`, it calls the function `format_pirogis`. i.e, for each element in `pirogis_stuffings`, you are printing the price of the element ($10 for potato and $12.5 for the rest).